# take tar and copy to remote server and extract that tar

Tags: linux, ssh, tar

I want to take tar from a logged in shell and take that tar file to a remote host and then extract the tar file over there.
I've got below command but the tar itself is not creating.

```
time=`date`
timestamp=`date +%F_%H%M`
backpfilename=db${timestamp}.tar.gz

cd /home/aryan/ && tar -cvzf $backupfilename | ssh root@remoteserver 'cd /home/aryantest/ && tar -xvzf $backpfilename'
```

Comment: Google 'tar over ssh'

Answer (score 10):

You can extract the tar file directly on the other side without writing it to disk:

`tar czv <files>| ssh root@remoteserver 'cat | tar xz -C /remotedir'`

You can use this even with `netcat` to copy files around.

If you want a progress bar you can use `pv` for this. It will print the speed to stdout so you can check how fast it is copying:

`tar czv <files> | pv | ssh root@remoteserver 'cat | tar xz -C /remotedir'`

If you already have that tar file, you can use `pv` to pipe it through ssh:

`pv backupfile.tgz| ssh root@remoteserver 'cat | tar xz -C /remotedir'`

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
cd /home/aryan
tar cfvz /dev/stdout . |
    ssh root@remoteserver 'cat > file.tar.gz && tar zxvf file.tar.gz'
```

You just need to adapt it a bit

#### Note

`/dev/stdout` can be replaced by `-`.

The basic way to create compressed files with tar is : `tar opts file.ext dir/`. Here we explicitly replace the destination filename with `STDOUT` to be able to stream it via ssh.

Comment: Thanks.. I've made the necessary changes. Can you please let me know in detail about  tar -cvzf - /home/aryan/db   where usually tar command will be like      tar -cvzf filename.tar.gz filename/    I am confused in this two tar commands. Both of them take tar